# Every time the button is clicked, insert a custom GroupBox in the FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a layout for a delivery system integrated with ifood for my company and I wanted the order data to be in personalized GroupBox. Name at the moment I'm testing the insertion inside the FlowLayoutPanel with the Button's EventClick.

However, I wanted you to insert a GroupBox like this:

[image]

It's possible?

Comment: I do not like FlowLayoutPanel because it is limited in what it can do.  If a FlowLayoutPanel does not do what you want create your own by adding child Panels to a Main Panel.  In this case you do not know how many child panels you are going to have until the order is completed.  Add child panels to a main panel in this case is better because you can keep on chainging the sie of the two dimensional array : 1 x1, 1 x 2, 2 x 2, 3 x 2,  3 x 3, 4 x 3, 4 x 4, etc.

Comment: I decided to create a UserObject and fast it today that is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a similar panel by pressing the button. I would advise you to make a new `FlowlayoutPanel` object (hereinafter FLP) with each button.

1. Record in an array (for example, `List <>` or `Dictionary <>`) information about the created orders of the order.
2. Add an event to a new panel copy (FLP) to delete and delete the recording in the array in which information about the order points is stored.
3. For each Label, set the name by the type `flp_id-client-name` and `flp_id-delivery-order-id`, where flp_id is the `Tag` of FLP.

However, you may encounter the difficulties of an even layout, so i advise you to use `Flowlayoutpanel` only as a parent container, and make subsidiaries from the object `TablelayoutPanel`.

If your question was how to extract data from new objects, then you should use the recipe of all the elements of the panel through Linq:

```
var _listLabels = FLP.Controls()
                    .OfType<Label>()
                    .Where(w => w.Name.Contains(FLP.Tag));

// In your case, you need to use the foreach
int delivery_order_id = int.Parse(_listLabels
                    .Where(w => w.Name == $"{FLP.Tag}-delivery-order-id")
                    .Select(s => s.Text).First());
string client_name = _listLabels
                    .Where(w => w.Name == $"{FLP.Tag}-client-name")
                    .Select(s => s.Text).First();
```